# TypeScript complex generic method

Tags: typescript

I currently have this method

```
create<T extends ElementType | string>(type: T): Element<T>;
```

which uses

```
export type ElementType = 'ExtensionElements' | 'Documentation';

export type Element<T> =
  T extends 'ExtensionElements' ? ExtensionElements :
    T extends 'Documentation' ? Documentation :
      GenericElement;
```

This method is in a `.d.ts`, and it guarantees the result is always typed, so that

```
const e1 = obj.create('ExtensionElements');
      ^^ type is ExtensionElements

const e2 = obj.create('Documentation');
      ^^ type is Documentation

const e3 = obj.create('Other');
      ^^ type is GenericElement
```

---

Now, I'd like to let the users of this method *extend* the possible typed choices, so that, for example

```
type CustomElementType = 'Other' | ElementType;

type CustomElement<T> =
  T extends 'Other' ? CustomOtherElement : Element<T>;

const e4 = obj.create<CustomElementType, CustomElement>('Other');
      ^^ type is CustomOtherElement
```

However this doesn't seem to work correctly, as I always receive an union of all types, and I cannot use arbitrary strings.

Do you have any other idea how I could implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an interface to map from the string type to the true type. Since interfaces are open ended clients can use module augmentation to add extra options:

```
// create.ts
export declare let obj: {   
    create<T extends ElementType | string>(type: T): Element<T>;
}
type ExtensionElements = { e: string }
type Documentation = { d: string }
type GenericElement = { g: string }

export type ElementType = 'ExtensionElements' | 'Documentation';
export interface ElementMap {
    'ExtensionElements': ExtensionElements;
    'Documentation': Documentation;
}
export type Element<T extends string> = ElementMap extends Record<T, infer E> ? E :
    GenericElement;

const e1 = obj.create('ExtensionElements'); // ExtensionElements
const e2 = obj.create('Documentation'); // Documentation
const e3 = obj.create('Else'); //GenericElement

// create-usage.ts
import { obj } from './create'
type CustomOtherElement = { x: string }

declare module './create' {
    export interface ElementMap {
        'Other': CustomOtherElement
    }
}
const e4 = obj.create('Other'); //  CustomOtherElement
```

If you want to do scoped extension you will need an extra function that will change the interface used to map the string to the object type. This method can just return the current object cast as the expected result (since types don't matter at runtime nothing needs to be different)

```
// create.ts
interface Creator<TMap = ElementMap>{
    create<T extends keyof TMap | string>(type: T): Element<TMap, T>;
    extend<TMapExt extends TMap>(): Creator<TMapExt>
}
export declare let obj: Creator
type ExtensionElements = { e: string }
type Documentation = { d: string }
type GenericElement = { g: string }

import { obj, ElementMap } from './create'
type CustomOtherElement = { x: string }

export type ElementType = 'ExtensionElements' | 'Documentation';
export interface ElementMap {
    'ExtensionElements': ExtensionElements;
    'Documentation': Documentation;
}
export type Element<TMap, T extends PropertyKey> = TMap extends Record<T, infer E> ? E : GenericElement;

const e1 = obj.create('ExtensionElements'); // ExtensionElements
const e2 = obj.create('Documentation'); // Documentation
const e3 = obj.create('Else'); //GenericElement


// create-usage.ts
export interface CustomElementMap extends ElementMap {
    'Other': CustomOtherElement
}
const customObj = obj.extend<CustomElementMap>()
const e4 = customObj.create('Other'); //  CustomOtherElement
```

Comment: Thank you! But is this valid only in case of re-export, right? What if I want to extend it just in a normal TS method scope? (basically in implementation code)

Comment: @LppEdd you want the extension to only be available in a particular scope ?

Comment: That would be an awesome plus, yes!

Comment: @LppEdd added a scoped extension version'

Comment: Thanks again! I think in the declaration version, the method should be `create<T extends string>`, without `ElementType`, or it won't compile, and in scoped example just remove the `export` from `CustomElementMap`.
I'm trying to understand the `infer E` part hahaha

Comment: @LppEdd it should compile with that .. does not matter much since `ElementType | string` will just be `string`. The `TMap extends Record<T, infer E>`just tells the compiler if `TMap` has a key `T` put in `E` the type of that key :)

Comment: Okay, my fault... I just used the wrong Type. Thanks :)